# Could not load file or assembly 'GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, mvvm-light, revit-api

I'm facing an annoying problem. Before I started using , everything went on smoothly. But tonight when I was trying to introduce into my View (which is a WPF Window)

```
                      <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger
                            EventName="SelectionChanged">
                            <mvvm:EventToCommand
                                Command="{Binding OnCategoryChangedCommand}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=comboBoxCategory}" />
                            <!--todo 数据绑定写入绑定源先触发？还是事件触发器先触发？-->
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Just ignore the Chinese content. :) 
I have correctly introduced the right namespaces like this:

```
    xmlns:mvvm="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

And I **succeeded** building.
 I started debugging (This project is not a WPF application, it's an Autodesk add-in dev project. So debugging starts from an Autodesk software). 
I click a button to trigger my Window, and immediately an exception was thrown:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
```

You can see the **"PublicKeyToken=null"**, because at the 1st time I faced this problem, I googled for this question, and got a solution of changing into MVVMLightStd10. I tried, and still got the above exception. Can anyone help? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several similar issues were recently discussed in the [Revit API discussion forum](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/bd-p/160), e.g., [missing System.ComponentModel.Annotations v4.2.0.0](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/missing-system-componentmodel-annotations-v4-2-0-0/m-p/8255546).

Here is an edited version of that solution and pointers to further by The Building Coder, on [Loading Add-In Support DLLs](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2018/09/support-dlls-zero-document-state-and-forge-accelerator-update.html#3).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I found you quite active on both API forum and here. Your code sample is a good one for new coder. Luckily, my program went well, but not with exactly your solution. Dunno why, maybe I used GACUtil command line command to include System.Windows.Interactivity with OLDER version in Blend SDK, but not restarted my computer.(I seldom restart my computer to be honest). Anyway, the day after when I post my question here, (I mean today), problem gone~.

Comment: good. thank you for your appreciation! please upvote my answer then. i reboot all my devices regularly. all software (except trivial stuff, like mine :-)) has bugs and needs regular cleaning.